# How to find a conditional nearest value in a sorted list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Imagine we have the following code:

```py
val_list = [1000,2000,2500,3200,4000,4200,4800,4900,5000,5001,5002,5003]
val_dict = {"a":1000,"b":2000,"c":2500,"d":3200,"e":4000,"f":4200,"g":4800,"h":4900,"i":5000,"j":5001,"k":5002,"l":5003}

sig_letters = ["a","b","d","f","h","i","k","l"]
```

Essentially, we have a sorted list of some values. These values are also the values of another dictionary.

The associated keys then may (or may not) be in another list.

Let's say I have an interest in the number "5000" from `val_list` and I want to find the nearest significant letter excluding itself.

I can't figure out how to implement finding the nearest significant letter. Since in this case, the nearest significant letter is actually `"k": 5002` which is 2 index positions away from `"i":5000`.

`"h":4900` is not an acceptable answer since the absolute difference between |4900-5000| = 100 while |5002-5000| = 2.

I can't figure out how to get something to test if 5002 is closer to 5000 before the program tests 4900 is closer. Since the keys for both 5002 and 4900 are in `sig_letters`, it should test 5002 first to break the loop.

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding it wrong, how come `j:5001` isn't the closest to `5000`?

Comment: j isn't in the `sig_letters` list therefore it is not the letter I want to pull out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the dict to only entries that are in `sig_letters` and a value not equal to the query value. Using a comprehension and then use `min` with a `abs` as a key function to find the dict entry of interest:

```
>>> x=5000
>>> min({k:v for k,v in val_dict.items() if k in sig_letters and v!=x}.items(), key=lambda e: abs(x-e[1]))
('k', 5002)
```

With Python 3.x, `.items()` is a dynamic [dict view object](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). It is fast and updated as the underlying dict changes.

If you are using Python 2.7, use [.viewitems()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems) instead of items() (and consider updating to Python 3.x...)

Comment: Wow and written so simply! Thank you! I'm still a newbie in all things programming but I like this!

Answer (score 1):

It would appear all three collections are sorted (in the case of the dictionary, 'a' will always have a lesser value than 'b', and so on). This makes things very simple - look at either side of the letter in `sig_letters`

```py
def absolute_difference(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a - b if a > b else b - a

def nearest(val: int) -> str:
    global val_list, val_dict, sig_letters

    exact_key = None

    # Find the corresponding key in val_dict (catch not found)
    for key, value in val_dict.items():
        if value == val:
            exact_key = key

    # Find exact_key's index in sig_letters  (catch ValueError)
    exact_index = sig_letters.index(exact_key)

    # Get values to left and right (catch out of bounds)
    left = sig_letters[exact_index-1]
    right = sig_letters[exact_index+1]
    left_val = val_dict[left]
    right_val = val_dict[right]


    if absolute_difference(left_val, val) < absolute_difference(right_val, value):
        return left
    else: 
        return right
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In my minimally reproducible example, yes all three are sorted, but in the actual dataset only, the first list (`val_list` equivalent) is sorted. The dictionary dataset is actually like a dictionary within a dictionary, and nothing else is sorted.